# Is it true that $\Big|\widehat{f|f|^{q-2}}\Big|^2=\widehat{|f|^{q-1}}^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $g(x)=f(x)|f(x)|^{q-2}$ where $q>2$ and $f\in \mathcal C^\infty _0(\mathbb R^d)$. First of all, is $g\in \mathcal C_0^\infty (\mathbb R^d)$ ?

Then I was wondering if $$|\hat g(\xi)|^2=|\widehat{f^{q-1}}(\xi)|^2$$

was true. The only thing I get is 
$$|\hat g(\xi)|^2=\hat g(\xi)\overline{\hat g(\xi)}=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x)|f(x)|^{q-2}f(y)|f(y)|^{q-2}e^{-2i\pi x\cdot \xi}e^{2i\pi y\cdot \xi}dxdy, $$
but I can't get $$\int_{\mathbb R^d}\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x)^{q-1}f(y)^{q-1}e^{-2i\pi x\cdot \xi}e^{2i\pi y\cdot \xi}dxdy.$$

Any idea ?

Comment: The title does not match the question. In general, the absolute value of the fourier transform does not equal the fourier transform of the absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the absolute value of the fourier transform does not equal the fourier transform of the absolute value. Consider, for example, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/524131).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. In fact my question refer to my other question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2595784/why-f-q-lq-mathbb-rd-leq-leftfq-1-gfq-1-right). If it was true, then I could understand the inequality, but if it's not true in general, how can I conclude in my question in the post ?